# converting data from mssql to mysql and issue in loading file

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, image

i have a mssql document which I convert to to mySql, 
i have a feild in mssql named IMG and the type is image, something like this 
**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
is stored in that field, how can i retrieve the image from this code? i dont have much information about these things and mssql. so that i dont know what is the code to search the instruction on net or stackoverflow.

as to mention , the table and data in it is working in .NET 
please help me in this matter.

Comment: Look the interclassement maybe

Comment: yes i do, i treat it as a BLOB but no result.

Comment: the code is already working in .NET and mssql

Comment: @jeanDoux what do you mean by interclassment?

Comment: it's the collation, what is the default collation in your sql server and what's the mysql collation (utf8, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should run it through [hex2bin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php). That should return you the binary data.

```
var_dump(hex2bin('FFD8FFE000104A464946000101010060'));
```

But, if you just need to import the data, using a `BLOB` field should be enough: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

And if you are just trying to make the code, which shows the image, you also need to set the correct header, before rendering. In case of the fragment above:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```